# Async Monitoring Azure Service Bus With Worker Role

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a worker role monitoring an Azure Service bus that can potentially receive thousands of messages at peak times. I realize I can use my cloud service to create multiple instances of the worker role (competing consumers), and scale that way, but I would also like for each worker instance to asynchronously handle multiple messages as well.

So my question in this; in my Client.OnMessage handler, can I call an async function that goes off on another thread, and the OnMessage resumes by reading the next message? Ideally, that would only happen a defined number of times.

For example:

```
 Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
            {
                try
                {
                   await ProcessCurrentMessage(receivedMessage);
                   // Would like to launch this asynchronously X times 
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    receivedMessage.Abandon();
                   //Handle error
                }
            });


  public async void ProcessCurrentMessage(BrokeredMessage receivedMessage)
  {  
      // Get properties from this message and do stuff
  }
```

What I am trying to do is to scale by having each worker role handle x amount of messages at a time, leveraging the CPU on that cloud service, and enhance that by adding more cloud instances. If I had 20 messages In the queue and 10 consumers, 10 would start (1 per competing consumer), then the 11th message would wait until one finished, etc. That seems kind of like a road block if each message took several minutes to process.

Appreciate any advice or tips.

Comment: Client.OnMessage has an overload that takes an OnMessageOptions object, in which you can define the number of concurrent messages to process. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31606869/1453907

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parallelize an azure worker role?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589239/how-to-parallelize-an-azure-worker-role)